# Removing the "on/off" white rectangle from my homepage (WPtouch)

Tags: css, plugin-wptouch

I use the WPtouch plugin (here: [r-bloggers.com](http://r-bloggers.com)), and some of my visitors are getting a white rectangle on the homepage, with a "on/off" option for the theme. The problem is that it only appears to some of the users, and clears after a little bit.

I read online it might be a conflict with another plugin, or a theme, but I don't wish to change any of these (they are all important for the function of the site), instead, I'd like to remove this box completely - is that possible?

Any other suggestions? (I have the plugin on "restricted mode" already - that doesn't help)

Answer (score 0):

use this chrome extension for opening mobile version your site.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg/related

switch android mode.than use developer tools for finding issue which mention above.I could not find any option as "On/OFF".